# React Module parse failed: Unexpected token on non-null assertion operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, null, jsx

I am trying to add the body of a note component in my react page, and I am using a non-null assertion operator to do so (Line 23)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';


const NotePage = () => {
  
    const { noteId } = useParams();

    let [note, setNote] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        getNote()
    }, [noteId])

    let getNote = async () => {
        let response = await fetch(`/api/notes/${noteId}`)
        let data = await response.json()
        setNote(data)
    }

    return (
    <div>
      <p>{note?.body}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default NotePage
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
./src/pages/NotePage.js 57:10
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (57:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|       columnNumber: 7
|     }
>   }, note?.body));
| };
| export default NotePage;
```

I have tried removing the non-null assertion operator but I then get the error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'body')`

Comment: Apparently your compiler does not understand JSX. How did you set up React?

Comment: Could you please share more details about the file extension and the package.json?